# Build tastypie resource in view?

Tags: django, django-views, tastypie

I already know how to create ModelResource in tastypie. For example, I have UserResource in resources.py and User in models.py. However in views.py, I have a view called match_user where it takes the list of all user and match to request.user. It return a render_to_response html called mymatch.html. Everything works on the browser but I want to create an API for this particular match_user. How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: Do you need to filter an API endpoint, or serialize a resource in a View?

Answer (score -1):

I think the following answers your question:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = "user"
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()

    # User is only authorized to view his own details   
    def apply_authorization_limits(self, request, object_list):
        return object_list.filter(pk=request.user.pk)
```

Session authentication would work if the user has an active session and is already logged in. For more authentication options, see https://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/authentication_authorization.html?highlight=authentication#authentication-options